# WQL to get all log file names

Tags: event-log, wmi-query, wql

How to get all log file names in WQL?
I tried these but they do not work and returns no key:

```
select logfilename from Win32_NTEventlogFile
select logfile from Win32_LogEvent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select Name from Win32_NTEventlogFile